# Make GameObject “attach” properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script makes a cube "stick" to whatever it collided with. The problem is that when it's going at relatively high or medium speeds (or when the device itself is slow), the cube tends to "get a bit inside" what it collided with and then stick to it. What changes do I have to make to fix this?

In order for this script to work, one GameObject must have `bool _sticksToObjects = true;` and the other `bool _sticksToObjects = false;`

I have tried turning the `Rigidbody`'s `Collision Detection` mode to either `Continuous` or `Continuous Dynamic`

I think my script depends on frame rate. That may be where the problem lies.

Normal "Attach":

[image]

Abnormal "Attach":

[image]

```
Rigidbody _rigidBody;
Transform _meshTransform;
bool _sticksToObjects = true;

public Transform _stuckTo = null;
protected Vector3 _offset = Vector3.zero;

void Awake()
{
    GameObject CubeMesh = GameObject.FindWithTag ("CubeMesh");
    GameObject Cube = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Cube");

    _rigidBody = Cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    _meshTransform = CubeMesh.GetComponent<Transform> ();
}

void Update() 
{
    if (_stuckTo != null)
    {
        transform.position = _stuckTo.position - _offset;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
        if (!_sticksToObjects) {
            return;
        }

        _rigidBody.isKinematic = true;

        // Get the approximate collision point and normal, as there
        // may be multipled collision points
        Vector3 contactPoint = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 contactNormal = Vector3.zero;
        for (int i = 0; i < collision.contacts.Length; i++) {
            contactPoint += collision.contacts [i].point;
            contactNormal += collision.contacts [i].normal;
        }

        // Get the final, approximate, point and normal of collision
        contactPoint /= collision.contacts.Length;
        contactNormal /= collision.contacts.Length;

        // Move object to the collision point
        // This acts as setting the pivot point of the cube mesh to the collision point
        transform.position = contactPoint;

        // Adjust the local position of the cube so it is flush with the pivot point
        Vector3 meshLocalPosition = Vector3.zero;

        // Move the child so the side is at the collision point.
        // A x local position of 0 means the child is centered on the parent,
        // a value of 0.5 means it's to the right, and a value of -0.5 means it to the left
        meshLocalPosition.x = (0.5f * contactNormal.x);
        _meshTransform.localPosition = meshLocalPosition;

        if (_stuckTo == null || _stuckTo != collision.gameObject.transform) {
            _offset = collision.gameObject.transform.position - transform.position;
        }

        _stuckTo = collision.gameObject.transform;
    }
```

Here are some screenshots of the Unity editor:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @JoeBlow This doesn't change anything. And what do you mean by "drag connect in the Inspector"?

Comment: @JoeBlow I have edited my question to make things clearer.

Comment: This thing you are trying to do is quite hard to do properly, and cannot be done using builtin physics engine of unity3d.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Question now on bounty.

Comment: @JoeBlow Question now on bounty.

Comment: @JoeBlow LateUpdate is definitely better in my case. Update just causes weird results, object starting to move and rotate insanely.

Comment: Maybe I',m missing something because perhaps your script interacts with other scripts you haven't mentioned but the script you've posted seems quite complex for what you've said it should do (make something stick to something else). If I were trying this I'd break it down to as few lines as possible to start with & grow it from there e.g. position = the hit normal etc then start to work the Vector3s you need

Answer (score 6):

This is a well-known category of problem in game engineering and you'll be pleased to know the solution is relatively simple. You'll be pleased to hear there are similar, but much more complicated, problems that are actually solved in the same way. I'll try to explain.

Now here's the thing. It's quite often that the following question comes up...

> So I'm working on GTA. I have a humanoid, H, running around. She approaches vehicle V.  She opens the door and gets in and drives off. After that everything goes to hell in Mecanim and all the code stops working. What to do?

Surprisingly, the way that is done in games is:

## Surprisingly: you actually swap to totally different models at that point!!!!!

You have H and V in the game. But then you have an animation (say) for H climbing in to V.  But then, **you literally destroy the game objects of H and V,** and you **Instantiate (or just awake) a new, totally different, game object**, which is D ("a car being driven around by a lady").

(If you think about it, you can see that when you do this, you carefully adjust all the stuff in D, so that it **matches** what was "just then happening" in the frame, in relation to both H and V.  So for example, literally, you copy the transform, twist etc of the car V, to the new car-inside-D, if lady H has the SmearedMakeupEffect, you put the same SmearedMakeupEffect on the lady-within-D, you position all the bones identically, and so on.)

Another simple example of this is, you often get people asking, "my character C gets killed and I want it to become a ragdoll, how to?" In fact you *just swap to a totally new game object* you have all set up for that passage of the game. Indeed, if you have a character A ("Arnie") in a game, it's normal that you have 4 or 5 "different As" sitting offside the stage, so, there's "ragdoll A", "A who can dance" "A with weapon".  And indeed many of these are combos, you know "A on the horse" "A in the car" and so on.

So interestingly, the "real" solution here is,

## once they become a new connected thing, destroy them both and swap to a new game object altogether!

if you have made games "until you are blue in the face" from making games, this is just what you would do as a matter of course. Even though its' a simple situation, it's just easier in the long run.  After all, consider all the stuff you have to do when this happens:

1. make hitting object child of the other
2. turn off physics on the child
3. change the way your physics works for the whole thing
4. turn off or change the collider on the hitting object, perhaps making it part of the overall object
5. you'll likely have some sort of new "separation" physics where it can be knocked-off - you'd have to turn all that on
6. likely change minor issues like sound effects, colors etc

As you can see it's a huge chore doing all this stuff, and indeed it's one of those things it's just "easier to do properly" and change to a new model.

---

All that being said, I know you want a Quick Script Solution you can Paste In :)  Here it is...

Step 0, You'll create "YourScript" which goes on the "main" cube.  it will "catch" another cube moving around.

YourScript will look basically like this ...

```
   [System.NonSerialized] public bool isConnectedNow;
   void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
      GameObject theThingWeCaught = collision.gameObject
      Debug.Log("We caught this thing .. " + theThingWeCaught.name)
      // make it a child of us......
      theThingWeCaught.transform.parent = transform
      theThingWeCaught ... set kinematic
      theThingWeCaught ... probably disable the rigidbody
      theThingWeCaught ... probably disable the collider
      isConnectedNow = true;
```

That's really all you have to do.

Step 1, YOUR script must have a `public bool` like this

```
 [System.NonSerialized] public bool isConnectedNow;
```

Step 2, Here's `MyScript` which goes on the hitting cube, first we'll unit-test that your `isConnectedNow` bool is working

```
public Class MyScript:MonoBehaviour // attach to the "child" cube
 {
 public float correctXDistance;
 public float correctYDistance;
 public Transform bigCube;
 public YourScript yourScript;

 void Update()
  {
  string message = yourScript.isConnectedNow ? "free" : "stuck";
  Debug.Log("I am " + message);
  }
 }
```

attach, debug, and run.   Make the little cube stick and unstick from the big cube .. Watch the console.  it works?  So add this to `MyScript`

```
private void DistanceCorrectionX()
 {
 float xDistance = bigCube.position.x - transform.position.x;
 float xSign = Mathf.Sign(xDistance);
 float xDelta = Mathf.Abs(xDistance);
 float closenessPercentage = (xDelta/correctXDistance)*100f;
 if ( closenessPercentage<90f || closenessPercentage>110f)
    {
    // they are not close enough to quantize on this axis
    // this comes in to play when you have multiple axes
    return;  // do nothing.
    }
 float xShouldBe = bigCube.position.x + xSign * correctXDistance;
 Vector3 p = transform;
 p.x = xShouldBe; // be careful it's .y, .z etc for other axes
 transform.position = p;
 }
```

for now call that in Update() in MyScript like this

```
 void Update()
  {
  Debug.Log("I am " yourScript.isConnectedNow ? "free" : "stuck");
  if (yourScript.isConnectedNow) DistanceCorrectionX();
  }
```

Now actually Play and make it stick.  Now, since it's running in `Update` simply while Play look at the Inspector for `MyScript` and **adjust the value of correctXDistance** to get the exact look you want. When yo have decided on a value, unPlay and put that in as the final value you wish.

Next, in `DistanceCorrectionX` simply duplicate all the code and do it again for the Y axis `DistanceCorrectionX`.  If you also do Z, do that.

Finally. Note you will have a lot of messy code, like this...

```
 void Update()
  {
  // handle all the DistanceCorrectionX etc as seen above.
  
  if (yourScript.isConnectedNow)
      {
      .. turn off the collider on me
      }
  else
      {
      .. turn on the collider on me
      }
  }
```

and so on, there's "many little things" you'll need to do.

Don't forget also, overwhelmingly you may want to make the hitting object **a child of** the big object, depending on your situation.  (Then of course they would move around together as a unit.)

Note that in the positioning code above I just showed it as position, not local position, for pedagogic clarity.  If you want to do them flinging around, and spinning and so on, you'd make the hitting object a child of the other and you would use `localPosition` in the same way.  Enjoy.

Comment: Very good answer with a lot effort put into it. But, I'm having trouble implementing your scripts: I'm getting plenty of errors. Can you please upload an example project to simplify the process? Thanks. You'll immediately receive your bounty award if your project works properly and solves the problem.

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks for the wonderful answer. After 3 hours of "head-scratching", I'm afraid I'm getting multiple errors too (11 errors).

Comment: I think @PikPok 's suggestion is right. A working example project would be really helpful and deeply appreciated from me. :) Again, excellent answer. I thank you for that.

Comment: @JoeBlow As I told you before, I get 11 different errors. I can't post all of them: it wouldn't make any sense. It would take too much time and effort to fix all of them one by one. Personally, I believe that an example project is the most efficient way to solve this.

Comment: @JoeBlow With all respect, no. I'm an advanced programmer who happens to be new to Unity. For sure, I didn't forget any variables or anything of that sort. I believe the errors come from my possible misunderstanding of your (again, very good) answer. In such complex problem-solving, many things could "get lost in translation". and English is not my native language ;) Again, a simple example project is the most efficient way out.

Comment: Do you mean `DistanceCorrectionX` ?  Sure, I just copied it from a project. Of course every game will need slightly different code.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Ahh .. allow me to explain.  As it says above in Step 1, **Step 1, YOUR script must have a public bool like this**  `[System.NonSerialized] public bool isConnectedNow;`  My post above is dealing with the (difficult) "second" issue of "***correcting*** connected cubes".  This post takes it for granted that you already have a system to connect cubes  :)  ie, YOU will have written a script with the functionality "isConnectedNow".  I'm sorry, I assumed you had that already...

Comment: YES THERE IS: make the arriving cube, the child of the master cube. That's what you do. (Sorry I forgot to type that in my edit there - done now.) You would still have turn off the collider etc on the new child.

Comment: no, it's just OnCollisionEnter.  at that point, you attach the other cube (make it a child) and in fact you get rid of the RigidBody on the other cube, so that sort of thing is not called any more

Comment: precisely. you use the variable `isConnectedNow` to know that!  there's no other way.

Comment: I don't know how clear I can be.  (1) to do what you say you have to use a boolean variable, a property if you will.  (2) you have to make the variable yourself, `isConnectedNow` (3) in my outline code sample it shows **how to do that**.  you set it true when the cube joins you; later when you "throw the cube away" you will have to set it false.   OnCollisionStay is completely and totally **unrelated**, it is not what you think.  OnCollisionStay relates to measuring "scraping" movements in PhysX and has absolutely no connection to two bodies which "are touching" ("at rest" together).

Comment: The only way it will not be connected, is, if you disconnect it.  there is no way it can "disconnect itself".  So, when you disconnect it (for whatever reason) be sure to remember to set the boolean to false.  For example, in your game it may stay connected for perhaps 5 seconds.  Use a timer (`Invoke`) and then run your code which disconnects it (perhaps "throwing it across the room" - or whatever happens in your game)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way that comes to my mind is:

Inside of the "collision enter" check the distance between these objects and move the one that should stick to the other one a bit away.

As you see in the picture the distance between A and B should be equal to the sum of the widths divided by 2 (with a small threshold of course). If the distance is less than the sum of the widths / 2 then you have an abnormal "attach" and you have to move one of the objects away. It's not really difficult to accomplish that.

[image]